# Closed range for a continuous linear transformation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I have a Banach space $B$ and a continuous linear transformation $F:B \rightarrow B\times B$. One of the induced transformations $F(1):B \rightarrow B$ and $F(2):B \rightarrow B$ into the factors of the product has closed range. Must F have closed range? I have the max norm on the product, i.e., $\|F(x) \| = max\{\|F(1)(x)\|, \|F(2)(x)\|\}$ for $x$ in $B$. I was hoping to use the minimum moduli of the
$F(i)$ to provide an affirmative answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider $F(x)=(f(x),0)$ where $f$ does not have closed range.

Comment: I felt _sure_ there was a simple counter-example to the question as stated, but was trying with the _identity_ as the other factor.  D'oh!

Comment: Thanks much, Bill. It is embarassing not to have considered mapping into one of the factors (I should have known better).

Comment: Does the answer change if the linear maps $F(i)$ must both be nonzero?

Comment: No; make the mapping into into the second factor rank one instead of rank zero.